# What data type to use in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need save some values in array by key, for example:

```
var arr = ['N' => 1, 'M' => 2, 'P' => 3];
```

What data type I need use in C# for this?
I tried `ArrayList` class, but it does a simple array.

Comment: Looks like some name-value pairs collection. Look at `Dictionary`.

Comment: use a `Dictionary<char, int>`

Answer (score 8):

You want to use a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Complete example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var arr = new Dictionary<char, int> {
            {'N', 1},
            {'M', 2},
            {'P', 3},
        };

        foreach (var pair in arr) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ": " + pair.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

An `IDictionary<string, int>` should do the trick.  Something like:

```
var arr = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "N", 1 },
    { "M", 2 },
    { "P", 3 }
};
```

(Or even an `IDictionary<char, int>` if those values should be `char` instead of `string`.)

Comment: You also need an import. [`using System.Collections.Generic;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<char, int>` or `Dictionary<string, int>` or you can also use an `enum` such as:

```
public enum EnumName
{
    N,
    M,
    P
}
```

Comment: Enum is a good idea if you need predefined structure with strings and their integer counterparts. `char` will require things like `nameof(N)[0]`, which aren't nice in my oppinion.

Comment: enum is not designed for storing variable data. you cant change values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Dictionary<string, int>`, or Dictionary` if you wish to reference multiple types of values.

Comment: What does this answer adds to existing answers?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried a Hashtable, it would allow the key value pairs

Comment: While you can use `Hashtable` it's inferior to strongly-typed `Dictionary<>`.

Comment: I defiantly agree to that